# In School Idol Festival, what is the maximum event points you can get without expending Loveca (Love Stones), disregarding leveling?

Tags: school-idol-festival

So, I was trying to bend my mind over some numbers, trying to see how many event points you can get in the game without expending cash (Love Stones / Loveca) to replenish LP.

Since there are SO many variables, I have to limit them:

1. The player is of average skill. He can clear Hard Hits or the Event Song on Medium with an average combo of "A" (sometimes B, sometimes S) but always score "S".
2. He only uses LP to play Hits on Hard. He never misses a note (bad or better harvests the event token). He never runs out of HP/Stamina during a song.
3. The player never attempts the event song on Hard, Easy or EX.
4. He starts the event with ZERO LP (or just grinds his LP to zero by quitting songs).
5. He has infinite rank, so he never levels up from song EXP.

So given these rules, we have:
[Wiki Link to the Unofficial Game Wiki](http://decaf.kouhi.me/lovelive/index.php?title=Gameplay#Events)

```
LP regenerated per day: 240 LP
Total Event Duration: 10 days (2,400 LP).
Tokens awarded per Hard Hits: 16 tokens. 
(equals 16 event points) - Song Cost: 15LP - 
Total Hits Songs played during the event: 160 songs, 2,560 tokens / event points.
-----------------------------------------------------------
Cost of an Event Song (medium): 30 tokens.
Event points awarded by a Medium Event Song: 138 event points  
(assuming he gets average of "A" combo and always "S" score.
Total Event Songs Played: 85 (10 leftover tokens unused).
Total event points from event songs: 11730 points.
----------------------------------------------------------
Total event points earned: 14,290
```

Now, the real question is: is this correct? If it is wrong, what is the maximum event points he can earn?

> PS: I know he won't start with empty LP, and that he will gain full LP when leveling up, but lets keep that aside, because factoring leveling in will be messy.

Bonus credits: How much song EXP will he earn during the event?

Comment: With both the ios and android tags, I'm going to assume the game works exactly the same on both, and obviates the need for either tag.

Comment: @Frank you are correct, the game is exactly the same (nicely ported BTW)... But do the tags really need to go?

Comment: Platform tags exist in a somewhat wonky state; we use them to differentiate if you're asking about a specific version of the game.  If the game worked differently in some manner between android and ios, say, then you'd use one of the tags so we know which version you're asking about, and can help with that version.  In the event the game is the same across all platforms, then there's no need for a platform tag, as it doesn't matter which version you're talking about.

Comment: @Frank A-OK! wilco!